How can I re-export a package's full set of types?
Package foo has many useful TypeScript interfaces that I want exposed transitively through package bar to consumers (represented as package baz), but I cannot find an elegant way to re-export that full set of types (namespace?) for downstream use. foo is a frequently changing dependency which I do not strictly maintain. It's important that its interfaces automatically reflect through bar, as bar is the sole provider of foo to baz.
Consider the following package dependency chain:
foo -> bar -> baz

Now consider some basic implementations:
// pkg foo
export interface Fooz { x: number }

// pkg bar
import * as foo from 'foo';

// Objective: get all interfaces/types re-exported through this package
export type FooMod = import('foo');
// ^ This would be ideal, but not supported
// Module 'foo' does not refer to a type, but is used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof import('foo')'?ts(1340)

// pkg baz
import * as bar from 'bar';

// This is my end customer's package. How can they get to interfaces from `foo`, hosted by `bar`? 
// e.g. observe the return type:
const doStuffWithBar = (): bar.FooMod.Fooz => {
  // 
}

Things I've tried so far:

export FooMod = typeof foo;. typeof foo creates a new type, and is lossy. It may bring over types from all entities physically present in the module, but types/interfaces from the foo module are all dropped. This is not adequate.
export FooMod = import('foo'). This produces a TS error, mentioned inline in comments.

Without a solution, I have to force my customers to actually install the foo module to access its top-level types. I could also inline exports in bar for all types in foo, but that's not sustainable, and given the size and change rate of foo, the worst outcome.
Is such a solution feasible?

Use export * (as X)? from 'package' in Bar. If you want to import the types directly in Baz, skip the as <X>, otherwise you can import the namespace in Baz like the example below:
Foo
// index.ts
export interface Test {
  a: string
}

Namespace import in Baz
Bar
// index.ts
export type * as Foo from 'foo';

Baz
import { Foo } from 'bar';

let a: Foo.Test;


Direct type imports in Baz
Bar
// index.ts
export type * from 'foo';

Baz
import { Test } from 'bar';

Edit: As noted by OP's comment, even with export types the non-type exports in Foo will also show up when importing in Baz. But they can neither be used in Baz, as typescript will give the error: <variable> cannot be used as a value because it was exported using 'export type'. and it doesn't even look like they're really exported from Bar, only in name in the declrataion file.

This is almost it, but I wanted just types, not impls. I may have to settle for the impls too.

I gotchu -kinda-. What you can do is use export type .... in Bar. The one issue is that it doesn't hide Foo's non-type exports, but it does show a typescript error if the import is used as a value: <variable> cannot be used as a value because it was exported using 'export type'.  I know it's not perfect though, since the values can still be imported, even if they can't be used. I've edited the answer to reflect it.

@cdaringe It looks like the variables are exported only in name through the declaration file in Bar. If I don't include in source code in Bar other than export types ..., the generated index.js is practically empty, but that's not the case as soon as I remove types

Incredible--export type. That's good enough for my current use case! Thanks @brother :)

Happy to help @cdaringe! :)
